# How to run more forms simultaneously in one WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application at certain point I need to open another form. Since now, I did it using

```
Form2 childform = new Form2();
childform.ShowDialog();
```

But when I show the second Form using this code, I am unable to click on the first one. What do I need to do, to have two Forms opened, and be allowed to work with both (click on them, write into TextBoxes included etc.)?

Comment: childform.Show(); would do it....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, You should try `childform.Show()`.

Comment: Yet again, the most simple things get me.. Thanks